# What happens to this infinite sum?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume $W$ is $n$ by $n$ matrix and $r<1$ is a real number. Let $$Q = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (rW)^i=[I_n-rW]^{-1}$$

Now assume that the $i$'th row of matrix $W$ is multiplied by a constant real number $c$. Let this new matrix $U$. Let $$P=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (rU)^i=[I-rU]^{-1}$$ I am very intersted to know the relation between $Q$ and $P$ and if we can express entries of $P$ in terms of entries of $Q$.

Thanks.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (rW)^i=(I_n-rW)^{-1}$ does not always hold even if $r<1$.

Comment: Interesting. When it does not hold?

Comment: Yes yes you are right, I forgot to mention that entries of $W$ are all less than 1. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$U = \underbrace{\text{Diagonal matrix}(1,1,\ldots,c,1,\ldots,1)}_C W \tag{$\star$}$$
We have $$I - rW = Q^{-1} \implies W = \dfrac{I-Q^{-1}}r\text{ and } I -rU = P^{-1} \implies U = \dfrac{I-P^{-1}}r$$
Hence, from $(\star)$, we get that
$$\dfrac{I - P^{-1}}r = C\dfrac{I-Q^{-1}}r$$
\begin{align}
P & = \left(I - C\left(I-Q^{-1} \right) \right)^{-1} = \left(CQ^{-1}+I-C\right)^{-1} = \left(CQ^{-1} + (1-c)e_i e_i^T\right)^{-1}\\
& = QC^{-1} - (1-c)\dfrac{QC^{-1}e_ie_i^T QC^{-1}}{1+(1-c)e_i^T QC^{-1} e_i} \left(\text{By Sherman Morrison} \right)
\end{align}
[You can look up Sherman Morrison here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula#Statement)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, but as I said I believe $P$ has some relation with $Q$ (and not $Q^{-1}$) and I am looking for that.

Comment: @user54626 Have updated it now.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for the reference. Very helpful!

Comment: Another question: What happens if the whole matrix $W$ is multiplied by constant $c$ (Instead of just one row). Then is there any relation between $P$ and $Q$? (simpler than $n$ times using Sherman-Morrison formula)