# Power series of matrix which is multiplied by a constant factor $c<1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

(Important: THIS PROBLEM IS NOT DUPLICATED! Note that the case where just one row of $W$ is multiplied by constant $c$, can be handled by the Sherman-Morrison theorem, but the case where the whole matrix $W$ is multiplied by some constant $c$ does not solve that easy)

Assume $W$ is a non-negative $n\times n$ row stochastic matrix and $r<1$ is a real number. Let $$Q = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (rW)^i=[I_n-rW]^{-1}$$.

Now assume that the matrix $W$ is multiplied by a constant real number $c<1$. Let this new matrix $U$. Let $$P=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (rU)^i=[I-rU]^{-1}=[I-rcW]^{-1}$$ I want to know  to know the relation between $Q$ and $P$ and if we can express entries of $P$ in terms of entries of $Q$. Or is it possible to have bound on $P$ in terms of $Q$?

Thanks.

Comment: I was sure this was a duplicate of the other question you asked, but I see the difference now. It is my recommendation that you edit this question to point to the other post, just so it's clear that this is distinct from the other.

Comment: No, it is not duplicate. I've mentioned the difference!

Comment: Are you looking for a relationship other than the obvious $P = ((1-c)I+cQ^{-1})^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes Actually I believe P can be written in terms of Q.

Comment: My fault. I didn't read your previous question carefully and voted to close it. My apology. Since you have worded this new question, I won't vote to reopen the closed question.

Answer (score 0):

This case is much simply than the one in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365240/what-happens-to-this-infinite-sum). We have $I-P^{-1}=rcW=c(I-Q^{-1})$ and hence $P=\left(I-c(I-Q^{-1})\right)^{-1}$.

Comment: I think you mean $P=(I-c(I-Q^{-1}))^{-1}$. Yes I agree on this, but as I said I want $P$ as a expression of $Q$. Or a lower or upper bound on it.

Comment: @user54626 Thanks for catching the typo, but isn't $\left(I-c(I-Q^{-1})\right)^{-1}$ an expression in terms of $Q$?

Comment: Maybe we can use Woodbury matrix identity formual to make it an expression in terms of $Q$, but I'm not sure about it. Please take a look at answer of this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365240/what-happens-to-this-infinite-sum).